# Why Onvif authentication works only with disabled replay attack protection?

Tags: python-3.3, onvif

I am working on Onvif client in Python3.My authentication algorhitm is:

```
b64encode(sha1(b64decode(nonce.encode('utf-8')) + date_utc.encode('utf-8') + password.encode('utf-8')).digest())
```

Basically,

> b64encode(sha1(b64decode(nonce)) + date + password)

I have also created ONVIF profiles and synchronized date and time on camera. What am I doing wrong?
And used camera is AxisQ1604, fw version 5.50.03

Comment: I have the same problem, where you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The same nonce can be used only once, than cameras (should) discard any other usernametoken that uses the same nonce.

Comment: I generate nonce everytime I make a request.